# Bringing a div out of a wrapper div having a fixed height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div2` inside another `div1`. The `div1` has a fixed height and an overflow. Here is the scenario:

[image]

Where the outer dark yellow div is the `div1` (having a scroll which you can see on the right side), and the `div.box1-large`(light yellow border) is the `div2`. As you can see, the `div2`'s extra content is hidden inside the `div1` which I can see only when I scroll the `div1`. How can I bring the `div2` out of `div1`? Please note that `div1` has many other divs too inside it.

Here are the corresponding css:

```
.div1 {
background: #2a2a2a;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
padding: 10px;
min-height: 350px;
height: 350px;
overflow: auto;
```

}

```
.div2 {
    border: solid 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 420px;
    height: 270px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 9;
    top: 62px;
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is the initial div:

[image]

I tried to change `div1` css to

```
.div1 {
    background: #2a2a2a;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

But this removes the scroll in `div1` and shows:

[image]

What I want is the above secenario but with scroll in `div1`.

Comment: Increase `z-index` to some `10000` and try...

Comment: isnt it just `overflow :visible;`

Comment: The height may be causing problems, increase the height on div1.

Comment: @JonesJoseph `overflow: visible` does bring the div in front, but removes the scroll. I tried `overflow-y: auto` along with `overflow: visible`, but it again renders the `div2` inside `div1`.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Your solution doesn't work.

Comment: @NeelamKhan Obviously increasing height will show that div, but I want to show it on the same height.

Comment: @PrabhjotRai : if u could just draw some squiggly lines around what you are expecting. cuz without scroll and without increasing the parent height ,show the child divs?... not sure what you are getting at :)

Comment: @luciferous I have editied my post. Maybe the edit helps you. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. The way i understand it.

You want the *.div2* to be **detached** from the *div1* . But div1 should remain scroll-able  because of others *div..n*s inside it.

i guess `position:absolute` should do it.

Made a small fiddle, have a look see. Better view in **full screen**

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.div1 {
  background: #2a2a2a;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.inter {
  border: solid 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.div2 {
  border: solid 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 420px;
  height: 270px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 9;
}
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="inter">Something</div>
  <div class="div2 abs">Stuff Man</div>
  <div class="div2">What??</div>
  <div class="div2">What??</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this helps, or if it missed the mark completely !

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for this?

```
$(".div2").appendTo($(".div1").parent);
```